# JQuery Attribute Manipulation

Tags: jquery, attributes

When I search on the Internet about JQuery and I got the jquery cheat sheet.  At there, I am very confused about how to use the following under which condition.  Pls help me.

```
[attribute|=val]
[attribute*=val]
[attribute~=val]
[attribute$=val]
[attribute=val]
[attribute!=val]
[attribute^=val]
[attribute]
[attribute1=val1] [attribute2=val2]
```

What are the functions of these special character *, ~, $, !, ^?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to the [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

- `=`: [equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
- `^`: [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
- `$`: [ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)
- `!`: [not equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)
- `*`: [contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)
- `~`: [contains word](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)
- `|`: [contains prefix](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/)
- `[name]`: [has attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) `name`

Your last example can mean one of two things depending on whether it has a space in between or not:

- `[attr1=foo][attr2=bar]` means find elements that have an attribute `attr1` with value `foo` *and* `attr2` with value `bar`; but
- `[attr1=foo] [attr2=bar]` means find elements with attribute `attr1` with a value of `foo` *that have descendants* with an attribute `attr2` with value `bar`.

The space here makes an important semantic difference in the expression.